# Good, solid documentation of PHP DOM

Tags: php, dom

I've been trying to do some simple DOM parsing of HTML documents and am really shocked at how difficult it is to do.

I've looked into some of the many alternatives to PHP's DOM classes (like [simple xml parser](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php) and [simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)). I found a very effective [dom2array function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php#93717) too, which is useful for extremely basic parsing where you just want raw values of elements.

None of these alternatives is really compelling though.

[PHP documentation of the DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) is typically lacking in detail and largely useless. A lot of the comments are actually really helpful though.

The tutorials I've found online typically cover only the very very basics like writing a 20 line XML document or parsing all the p tags in a document. Meh.

Are there any sites (or books) that go into detail specifically on working with the DOM using PHP's DOM libraries?

Comment: You mentioned PHP Simple HTML DOM. Have you see the documentation? It's pretty clear... http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: Rather look at phpQuery or QueryPath or FluentDom. They use the jQuery API to some extend and are heaps easier. See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-querypath/index.html

Comment: I've tried all the "simple" libraries as well as PHP DOM. The simples are either unable to do basic things, like support xpath, poorly documented or just too simple. I'd like to use DOM, but I don't have the time to learn it. I'm leaning towards a tidy/regex solution. Not at all ideal, but easy. It just boggles my mind that there's not a simple way to parse HTML in PHP. I understand that parsing X/HTML can be a complicated task, needing powerful tools. But when you just want to remove some tags, grab the title, re-reference paths... %...(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have titled my post, "Easiest way to parse HTML DOM in PHP". 'Easiest' is not a very good word, I know. It's all relative to what you're trying to do. What I'm doing is pretty straight-forward. I want to parse standalone HTML documents and present the content in a different context.

These are the things I wanted to do:

- Parse basic properties like title and body
- Alter all file references (images, links, css, js) to point to a valid location
- Add/remove attributes from tags (dealing with 1995 HTML here)
- Strip inline styles

I ended up going with [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

It has a very small learning curve and gives easy read/write access to the DOM. End of story. It does seem to choke on nested elements sometimes though.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM is a language-independent interface and [documented in detail by the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html).

That being said, if your aim is extremely simple parsing of (typically) structured information, XML may not be the correct format in the first place; XML includes a variety of advanced features (namespaces, DTDs, XSLT, distinction between attributes and text, markup instead of structured information). If that's the case, consider [JSON](http://json.org/), which is [extremely easy to parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [generate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Answer (score 0):

Anything that says "DOM" in the name or claims to support it should support [the DOM API as defined by the W3C](http://www.w3.org/DOM/), and you should consider their documentation normative for everything but the language-specific parts.